# IntelliSense for XElement objects with XML schema

Tags: c#, linq, xsd, linq-to-xml, vb.net-to-c#

Reading an article called *"Increase LINQ Query Performance"* in July's MSDN magazine, the author states that using an `Imports` in VB providing a path to schema in the current project will turn IntelliSense on for XElement. In the code provided, he uses statements like `xelement.@name` to retreive attributes values and so on.

I did not try this out myself in VB but I would like to use that in C#. This really looks like LINQ to XSD.

Is there any equivalent in C#? It seems that it is not possible to use a namespace inside C# code, there is no `using` equivalent to this `Import` statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This post claims to have a link to a video that shows how to use VB9's XML Literals in C#. However, it only really discusses them and from what I can gather, you cannot use them in C#. http://blogs.msdn.com/bethmassi/archive/2008/07/03/teched-panel-vb-xml-literals-for-c-developers.aspx

Comment: That video isn't claiming to show how to use XML Literals in C#. It's explaining their use in VB9 so that non-vb developers can understand them.