# Does Linq-to-Xml queries support intellisence in C#?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

In my project I am using an XML-file for datastorage. I am accessing that file with linq-to-xml queries. Actually I have created that XML-file from my SQL-server database but as that tables in SQL contained  more that 50 columns, the resulting XML-file is also having more than 50 elements...

Now while applying queries I initially load that XML-file in XDocument object and after that applying queries on that.

My main problem is that as it contain more than 50 element it is very difficult to write queries without intellisence support. Why it is not supporting intellisence? What have I done wrong? What can I do to get intellisence support?

Comment: Not sure if it is a perfect dupe or not, but check this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912/intellisense-for-xelement-objects-with-xml-schema - the answer is you can't get Linq to Xml intellisense in C#.

Answer (score 4):

LINQ to XML is based on strings and it isn't confined to documents that follow some schema. That's the reason you don't get IntelliSense, VS has no information about the schema.

If this is really important for you, maybe using something like xsd.exe to generate classes that represent the schema would be better for you.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to get intellisense for Linq to Xml.
This is because you load a file at runtime and you expect it to have compile time intellisense. What if you would load a different file at runtime, would you then get a compile time error?

What you could do is generate classes from your Xml file and then deserialize your XML file into these classes. The you can use Linq To Objects to access the data.

[Here is some documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s.aspx) for creating your classes.